# Script runtime execution time limit

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, limit, batch-processing

My Google Apps Script is iterating through the user's Google Drive files and copying and sometimes moving files to other folders. The script is always stopped after certain minutes with no error message in the log.

---

EDITOR's NOTE: The time limit have varied over the time and might vary between "consumer" (free) and "Workspace" (paid) accounts but as of December 2022 most of the answers are still valid.

---

I am sorting tens or sometimes thousands files in one run.

Are there any settings or workarounds?

Comment: You can bend the rules by using the HTML Service to launch separate "iterations" of your script on sub-sets of your work. [Bruce McPherson has blogged about it.](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/htmlservice/parallel)

Comment: If you're a business customer, you can now sign up for [Early Access to App Maker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/apps-script-eap), which includes [Flexible Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#flexible_quotas_early_access).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63604878/

Comment: As of Aug 2022, for paid Workspace account, I see execution time limit of 1800s = half an hour.

Answer (score 97):

One thing you could do (this of course depends on what you are trying to accomplish) is:

1. Store the necessary information (i.e. like a loop counter) in a spreadsheet or another permanent store(i.e. ScriptProperties).
2. Have your script terminate every five minutes or so.
3. Set up a time driven trigger to run the script every five minutes(or create a trigger programmatically using the [Script service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_script)).
4. On each run read the saved data from the permanent store you've used and continue to run the script from where it left off.

This is not a one-size-fit-all solution, if you post your code people would be able to better assist you.

Here is a simplified code excerpt from a script that I use every day:

```
function runMe() {
  var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
  
  //do some work here
  
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var startRow= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_row');
  for(var ii = startRow; ii <= size; ii++) {
    var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    if(currTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME) {
      scriptProperties.setProperty("start_row", ii);
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("runMe")
               .timeBased()
               .at(new Date(currTime+REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT))
               .create();
      break;
    } else {
      doSomeWork();
    }
  }
  
  //do some more work here
  
}
```

NOTE#1: The variable `REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT` should be large enough for the new trigger to fire. (I set it to 5 minutes but I think it could be less than that).

NOTE#2: `doSomeWork()` must be a function that executes relatively quick( I would say less than 1 minute ).

NOTE#3 : Google has deprecated [`Script Properties`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties), and introduced [`Properties Service`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) in its stead. The function has been modified accordingly.

NOTE#4: 2nd time when the function is called, it takes the ith value of for loop as a string. so you have to convert it into an integer

Comment: Is there a limit on how often the trigger can go? I think there might be a trigger limit per 24 hours or something... Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this will work for add-on. Add-on timed-trigger only allows to execute once every hour. Do you know any other solution to keep a task running and process large amount of data from excel sheet.

Comment: This has the side-effect of leaving all the old-time-based triggers in the project's trigger list...  Not sure how expired time triggers are supposed to be expunged.

Comment: Google has deprecated this approach. Is there an alternative? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/script-properties

Comment: @iamtoc while script properties are disabled, you can still use PropertiesService. It's a very small edit

Comment: @staggart I don't mean to revoke this old thread but, for other people looking at it, you could set up another function on a daily/weekly timer that would remove all triggers that are specific time based for a  certain function

Comment: What is the use of the `REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT`, can't we only do `.at(new Date(currTime))`?

Comment: Please modify your script to: `var startRow= parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty('start_row'))` as getProperty returns string and not number.

Comment: If anybody could apply this to recursion approach , please have your answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738898/workaround-to-6-minutes-app-script-limits-on-google-drive-file-copying

Answer (score 72):

#### Quotas

> The maximum execution time for a single script is 6 mins / execution
>   - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

But there are other limitations to familiarize yourself with.  For example, you're only allowed a total trigger runtime of 1 hour / day, so you can't just break up a long function into 12 different 5 minute blocks.

#### Optimization

That said, there are very few reasons why you'd really need to take six minutes to execute.  JavaScript should have no problem sorting thousands of rows of data in a couple seconds.  What's likely hurting your performance are service calls to Google Apps itself.

> You can write scripts to take maximum advantage of the built-in caching, by minimizing the number of reads and writes. Alternating read and write commands is slow. To speed up a script, read all data into an array with one command, perform any operations on the data in the array, and write the data out with one command.
>   - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices

#### Batching

The best thing you can possibly do is reduce the number of service calls.  Google enables this by allowing batch versions of most of their API calls.

As a trivial example, **Instead of this**:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(i);
}
```

**Do this**:

```js
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(i, 100);
```

In the first loop, not only did you need 100 calls to deleteRow on the sheet, but you also needed to get the active sheet 100 times as well.  The second variation should perform several orders of magnitude better than the first.

#### Interweaving Reads and Writes

Additionally, you should also be very careful to not go back and forth frequently between reading and writing.  Not only will you lose potential gains in batch operations, but Google won't be able to use its built-in caching.

> Every time you do a read, we must first empty (commit) the write cache to ensure that you're reading the latest data (you can force a write of the cache by calling `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`). Likewise, every time you do a write, we have to throw away the read cache because it's no longer valid. Therefore if you can avoid interleaving reads and writes, you'll get full benefit of the cache.
>   - http://googleappsscript.blogspot.com/2010/06/optimizing-spreadsheet-operations.html

**For example, instead of this**:

```js
sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(1);
sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(2);
sheet.getRange("C1").setValue(3);
sheet.getRange("D1").setValue(4);
```

**Do this**:

```js
sheet.getRange("A1:D1").setValues([[1,2,3,4]]);
```

#### Chaining Function Calls

As a last resort, if your function really can't finish in under six minutes, you can chain together calls or break up your function to work on a smaller segment of data.

You can store data in the [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/) (temporary) or [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) (permanent) buckets for retrieval across executions (since Google Apps Scripts has a stateless execution).

If you want to kick off another event, you can create your own trigger with the [Trigger Builder Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder) or setup a recurring trigger on a tight time table.

Comment: Thanks KyleMit, that's a very comprehensive answer!

Comment: *"That said, there are very few reasons why you'd really need to take six minutes to execute."* Try writing a script that processes e.g. stuff in Gmail, Drive, etc...

Comment: @Mehrdad, those seem like a few reasons :) but yeah, 95%+ scripts shouldn't run into this as a roadblock

Answer (score 34):

Also, try to minimize the amount of calls to google services. For example, if you want to change a range of cells in the spreadsheets, don't read each one, mutate it and store it back.
Instead read the whole range (using [Range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues%28%29)) into memory, mutate it and store all of it at once (using [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues%28Object%29)).

This should save you a lot of execution time.

Answer (score 17):

[Anton Soradoi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608327/3829407) seems OK but **consider using [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/)** instead of storing data into a temporary sheet.

```
 function getRssFeed() {
   var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();
   var cached = cache.get("rss-feed-contents");
   if (cached != null) {
     return cached;
   }
   var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://example.com/my-slow-rss-feed.xml"); // takes 20 seconds
   var contents = result.getContentText();
   cache.put("rss-feed-contents", contents, 1500); // cache for 25 minutes
   return contents;
 }
```

Also note that as of April 2014 the [limitation of script runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) **is 6 minutes**.

---

**G Suite Business / Enterprise / Education and Early Access users:**

As of August 2018, max script runtime is now set to 30 minutes for these users.

Comment: This seems to me the easiest way to solve the problem, as you don't need to set-up nor care about any other resources (spreadsheets, databases, ...) and all the script logic remains within the script itself. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give an example for a generalised function?

Comment: This is an excellent method, especially saves hitting an API way too many times and getting a limit strike.

Answer (score 12):

Figure out a way to split up your work so it takes less than 6 minutes, as that's the limit for any script. On the first pass, you can iterate and store the list of files and folders in a spreadsheet and add a time-driven trigger for part 2.

In part 2, delete each entry in the list as you process it. When there are no items in the list, delete the trigger.

This is how I'm processing a sheet of about 1500 rows that gets spread to about a dozen different spreadsheets. Because of the number of calls to spreadsheets, it times out, but continues when the trigger runs again.

Comment: To be precise, the max execution time is 6 minutes: "the current maximum script execution time limit (6 minutes)" as noted here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scriptdb

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed it.
Also, I use a 10min trigger for my script just to make sure there is no overlap between executions. I'm not sure how Google decides to start time-driven triggers, so a little buffer can't hurt.

Comment: SO you can store all your data into ScriptDb and do just some small part (because of 6min limit) and then continue in the next run (which will be triggered by timer). That`s sounds like good solution.

Comment: Also, you can now create triggers for any time you want, so my script creates a trigger 7 minutes in the future every time it starts (if it knows it will have to keep going).

Answer (score 6):

I have used the ScriptDB to save my place while processing a large amount of information in a loop.  The script can/does exceed the 5 minute limit. By updating the ScriptDb during each run, the script can read the state from the db and pick up where it left off until all processing is complete.  Give this strategy a try and I think you'll be pleased with the results.

Comment: Have a similar problem with a script that iterates through 750 email addresses on a spreadsheet. How do you store where the script left off and resume execution?

Comment: ScriptDb is deprecated.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using G Suite Business or Enterprise edition.
You can [register early access for App Maker](https://gsuite.google.com/campaigns/index__appmakereap.html) after App maker enabled your script run runtime will increase run time **from 6 minutes to 30 minutes** :)

More details about app maker [Click here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/)

Comment: Ya we can increase run time from 6 minutes to 30 minutes using Early access program but those apps cannot be deployed to public.

Comment: The App Maker product will be shut down on January 19, 2021
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9682494?p=am_announcement

Comment: This answer is obsolete. App Maker, was shutdown, and the Apps Script quota page was updated. As of Jun 15th, 2023, the script runtime execution limit is 6 minutes for consumer and Workspace accounts. Ref. for current quotas: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach based very heavily on [Dmitry Kostyuk's absolutely excellent article](https://medium.com/geekculture/bypassing-the-maximum-script-runtime-in-google-apps-script-e510aa9ae6da?sk=ca2b3c4d2fa429e02ba5f81a94d0c780) on the subject.

It differs in that it doesn't attempt to time execution and exit gracefully. Rather, it deliberately spawns a new thread every minute, and lets them run until they are timed out by Google. This gets round the maximum execution time limit, and speeds things up by running processing in several threads in parallel. (This speeds things up even if you are not hitting execution time limits.)

It tracks the task status in script properties, plus a semaphore to ensure no two threads are editing the task status at any one time. (It uses several properties as they are limited to 9k each.)

I have tried to mimick the Google Apps Script `iterator.next()` API, but cannot use `iterator.hasNext()` as that would not be thread-safe (see [TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)). It uses a couple of facade classes at the bottom.

I would be immensely grateful for any suggestions. This is working well for me, halving the processing time by spawning three parallel threads to run through a directory of documents. You could spawn 20 within quota, but this was ample for my use case.

The class is designed to be drop-in, usable for any purpose without modification. The only thing the user must do is when processing a file, delete any outputs from prior, timed out attempts. The iterator will return a given `fileId` more than once if a processing task is timed out by Google before it completes.

To silence the logging, it all goes through the `log()` function at the bottom.

This is how you use it:

```
const main = () => {
  const srcFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName('source folder',).next()
  const processingMessage = processDocuments(srcFolder, 'spawnConverter')
  log('main() finished with message', processingMessage)
}

const spawnConverter = e => {
  const processingMessage = processDocuments()
  log('spawnConverter() finished with message', processingMessage)
}

const processDocuments = (folder = null, spawnFunction = null) => {
  // folder and spawnFunction are only passed the first time we trigger this function,
  // threads spawned by triggers pass nothing.
  // 10,000 is the maximum number of milliseconds a file can take to process.
  const pfi = new ParallelFileIterator(10000, MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, folder, spawnFunction)
  let fileId = pfi.nextId()
  const doneDocs = []
  while (fileId) {
    const fileRelativePath = pfi.getFileRelativePath(fileId)
    const doc = DocumentApp.openById(fileId)
    const mc = MarkupConverter(doc)

    // This is my time-consuming task:
    const mdContent = mc.asMarkdown(doc)

    pfi.completed(fileId)
    doneDocs.push([...fileRelativePath, doc.getName() + '.md'].join('/'))
    fileId = pfi.nextId()
  }
  return ('This thread did:\r' + doneDocs.join('\r'))
}
```

Here's the code:

```
const ParallelFileIterator = (function() {
  /**
  * Scans a folder, depth first, and returns a file at a time of the given mimeType.
  * Uses ScriptProperties so that this class can be used to process files by many threads in parallel.
  * It is the responsibility of the caller to tidy up artifacts left behind by processing threads that were timed out before completion.
  * This class will repeatedly dispatch a file until .completed(fileId) is called.
  * It will wait maxDurationOneFileMs before re-dispatching a file.
  * Note that Google Apps kills scripts after 6 mins, or 30 mins if you're using a Workspace account, or 45 seconds for a simple trigger, and permits max 30  
  * scripts in parallel, 20 triggers per script, and 90 mins or 6hrs of total trigger runtime depending if you're using a Workspace account.
  * Ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas
  maxDurationOneFileMs, mimeType, parentFolder=null, spawnFunction=null
  * @param {Number} maxDurationOneFileMs A generous estimate of the longest a file can take to process.
  * @param {string} mimeType The mimeType of the files required.
  * @param {Folder} parentFolder The top folder containing all the files to process. Only passed in by the first thread. Later spawned threads pass null (the files have already been listed and stored in properties).
  * @param {string} spawnFunction The name of the function that will spawn new processing threads. Only passed in by the first thread. Later spawned threads pass null (a trigger can't create a trigger).
  */
  class ParallelFileIterator {
    constructor(
      maxDurationOneFileMs,
      mimeType,
      parentFolder = null,
      spawnFunction = null,
    ) {
      log(
        'Enter ParallelFileIterator constructor',
        maxDurationOneFileMs,
        mimeType,
        spawnFunction,
        parentFolder ? parentFolder.getName() : null,
      )

      // singleton
      if (ParallelFileIterator.instance) return ParallelFileIterator.instance

      if (parentFolder) {
        _cleanUp()
        const t0 = Now.asTimestamp()
        _getPropsLock(maxDurationOneFileMs)
        const t1 = Now.asTimestamp()
        const { fileIds, fileRelativePaths } = _catalogFiles(
          parentFolder,
          mimeType,
        )
        const t2 = Now.asTimestamp()
        _setQueues(fileIds, [])
        const t3 = Now.asTimestamp()
        this.fileRelativePaths = fileRelativePaths
        ScriptProps.setAsJson(_propsKeyFileRelativePaths, fileRelativePaths)
        const t4 = Now.asTimestamp()
        _releasePropsLock()
        const t5 = Now.asTimestamp()
        if (spawnFunction) {
          // only triggered on the first thread
          const trigger = Trigger.create(spawnFunction, 1)
          log(
            `Trigger once per minute: UniqueId: ${trigger.getUniqueId()}, EventType: ${trigger.getEventType()}, HandlerFunction: ${trigger.getHandlerFunction()}, TriggerSource: ${trigger.getTriggerSource()}, TriggerSourceId: ${trigger.getTriggerSourceId()}.`,
          )
        }
        log(
          `PFI instantiated for the first time, has found ${
            fileIds.length
          } documents to process. getPropsLock took ${t1 -
            t0}ms, _catalogFiles took ${t2 - t1}ms, setQueues took ${t3 -
            t2}ms, setAsJson took ${t4 - t3}ms, releasePropsLock took ${t5 -
            t4}ms, trigger creation took ${Now.asTimestamp() - t5}ms.`,
        )
      } else {
        const t0 = Now.asTimestamp()
        // wait for first thread to set up Properties
        while (!ScriptProps.getJson(_propsKeyFileRelativePaths)) {
          Utilities.sleep(250)
        }
        this.fileRelativePaths = ScriptProps.getJson(_propsKeyFileRelativePaths)
        const t1 = Now.asTimestamp()
        log(
          `PFI instantiated again to run in parallel. getJson(paths) took ${t1 -
            t0}ms`,
        )
        spawnFunction
      }

      _internals.set(this, { maxDurationOneFileMs: maxDurationOneFileMs })
      // to get: _internal(this, 'maxDurationOneFileMs')

      ParallelFileIterator.instance = this
      return ParallelFileIterator.instance
    }

    nextId() {
      // returns false if there are no more documents

      const maxDurationOneFileMs = _internals.get(this).maxDurationOneFileMs
      _getPropsLock(maxDurationOneFileMs)
      let { pending, dispatched } = _getQueues()
      log(
        `PFI.nextId: ${pending.length} files pending, ${
          dispatched.length
        } dispatched, ${Object.keys(this.fileRelativePaths).length -
          pending.length -
          dispatched.length} completed.`,
      )
      if (pending.length) {
        // get first pending Id, (ie, deepest first)
        const nextId = pending.shift()
        dispatched.push([nextId, Now.asTimestamp()])
        _setQueues(pending, dispatched)
        _releasePropsLock()
        return nextId
      } else if (dispatched.length) {
        log(`PFI.nextId: Get first dispatched Id, (ie, oldest first)`)
        let startTime = dispatched[0][1]
        let timeToTimeout = startTime + maxDurationOneFileMs - Now.asTimestamp()
        while (dispatched.length && timeToTimeout > 0) {
          log(
            `PFI.nextId: None are pending, and the oldest dispatched one hasn't yet timed out, so wait ${timeToTimeout}ms to see if it will`,
          )
          _releasePropsLock()
          Utilities.sleep(timeToTimeout + 500)
          _getPropsLock(maxDurationOneFileMs)
          ;({ pending, dispatched } = _getQueues())
          if (pending && dispatched) {
            if (dispatched.length) {
              startTime = dispatched[0][1]
              timeToTimeout =
                startTime + maxDurationOneFileMs - Now.asTimestamp()
            }
          }
        }
        // We currently still have the PropsLock
        if (dispatched.length) {
          const nextId = dispatched.shift()[0]
          log(
            `PFI.nextId: Document id ${nextId} has timed out; reset start time, move to back of queue, and re-dispatch`,
          )
          dispatched.push([nextId, Now.asTimestamp()])
          _setQueues(pending, dispatched)
          _releasePropsLock()
          return nextId
        }
      }
      log(`PFI.nextId: Both queues empty, all done!`)
      ;({ pending, dispatched } = _getQueues())
      if (pending.length || dispatched.length) {
        log(
          "ERROR: All documents should be completed, but they're not. Giving up.",
          pending,
          dispatched,
        )
      }
      _cleanUp()
      return false
    }

    completed(fileId) {
      _getPropsLock(_internals.get(this).maxDurationOneFileMs)
      const { pending, dispatched } = _getQueues()
      const newDispatched = dispatched.filter(el => el[0] !== fileId)
      if (dispatched.length !== newDispatched.length + 1) {
        log(
          'ERROR: A document was completed, but not found in the dispatched list.',
          fileId,
          pending,
          dispatched,
        )
      }
      if (pending.length || newDispatched.length) {
        _setQueues(pending, newDispatched)
        _releasePropsLock()
      } else {
        log(`PFI.completed: Both queues empty, all done!`)
        _cleanUp()
      }
    }

    getFileRelativePath(fileId) {
      return this.fileRelativePaths[fileId]
    }
  }

  // ============= PRIVATE MEMBERS ============= //

  const _propsKeyLock = 'PropertiesLock'
  const _propsKeyDispatched = 'Dispatched'
  const _propsKeyPending = 'Pending'
  const _propsKeyFileRelativePaths = 'FileRelativePaths'

  // Not really necessary for a singleton, but in case code is changed later
  var _internals = new WeakMap()

  const _cleanUp = (exceptProp = null) => {
    log('Enter _cleanUp', exceptProp)
    Trigger.deleteAll()
    if (exceptProp) {
      ScriptProps.deleteAllExcept(exceptProp)
    } else {
      ScriptProps.deleteAll()
    }
  }

  const _catalogFiles = (folder, mimeType, relativePath = []) => {
    // returns IDs of all matching files in folder, depth first
    log(
      'Enter _catalogFiles',
      folder.getName(),
      mimeType,
      relativePath.join('/'),
    )
    let fileIds = []
    let fileRelativePaths = {}
    const folders = folder.getFolders()
    let subFolder
    while (folders.hasNext()) {
      subFolder = folders.next()
      const results = _catalogFiles(subFolder, mimeType, [
        ...relativePath,
        subFolder.getName(),
      ])
      fileIds = fileIds.concat(results.fileIds)
      fileRelativePaths = { ...fileRelativePaths, ...results.fileRelativePaths }
    }
    const files = folder.getFilesByType(mimeType)
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      const fileId = files.next().getId()
      fileIds.push(fileId)
      fileRelativePaths[fileId] = relativePath
    }
    return { fileIds: fileIds, fileRelativePaths: fileRelativePaths }
  }

  const _getQueues = () => {
    const pending = ScriptProps.getJson(_propsKeyPending)
    const dispatched = ScriptProps.getJson(_propsKeyDispatched)
    log('Exit _getQueues', pending, dispatched)
    // Note: Empty lists in Javascript are truthy, but if Properties have been deleted by another thread they'll be null here, which are falsey
    return { pending: pending || [], dispatched: dispatched || [] }
  }
  const _setQueues = (pending, dispatched) => {
    log('Enter _setQueues', pending, dispatched)
    ScriptProps.setAsJson(_propsKeyPending, pending)
    ScriptProps.setAsJson(_propsKeyDispatched, dispatched)
  }

  const _getPropsLock = maxDurationOneFileMs => {
    // will block until lock available or lock times out (because a script may be killed while holding a lock)
    const t0 = Now.asTimestamp()
    while (
      ScriptProps.getNum(_propsKeyLock) + maxDurationOneFileMs >
      Now.asTimestamp()
    ) {
      Utilities.sleep(2000)
    }
    ScriptProps.set(_propsKeyLock, Now.asTimestamp())
    log(`Exit _getPropsLock: took ${Now.asTimestamp() - t0}ms`)
  }
  const _releasePropsLock = () => {
    ScriptProps.delete(_propsKeyLock)
    log('Exit _releasePropsLock')
  }

  return ParallelFileIterator
})()

const log = (...args) => {
  // easier to turn off, json harder to read but easier to hack with
  console.log(args.map(arg => JSON.stringify(arg)).join(';'))
}

class Trigger {
  // Script triggering facade

  static create(functionName, everyMinutes) {
    return ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)
      .timeBased()
      .everyMinutes(everyMinutes)
      .create()
  }
  static delete(e) {
    if (typeof e !== 'object') return log(`${e} is not an event object`)
    if (!e.triggerUid)
      return log(`${JSON.stringify(e)} doesn't have a triggerUid`)
    ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
      if (trigger.getUniqueId() === e.triggerUid) {
        log('deleting trigger', e.triggerUid)
        return ScriptApp.delete(trigger)
      }
    })
  }
  static deleteAll() {
    // Deletes all triggers in the current project.
    var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers()
    for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i])
    }
  }
}

class ScriptProps {
  // properties facade
  static set(key, value) {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) {
      ScriptProps.delete(key)
    } else {
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(key, value)
    }
  }
  static getStr(key) {
    return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(key)
  }
  static getNum(key) {
    // missing key returns Number(null), ie, 0
    return Number(ScriptProps.getStr(key))
  }
  static setAsJson(key, value) {
    return ScriptProps.set(key, JSON.stringify(value))
  }
  static getJson(key) {
    return JSON.parse(ScriptProps.getStr(key))
  }
  static delete(key) {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty(key)
  }
  static deleteAll() {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties()
  }
  static deleteAllExcept(key) {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
      .getKeys()
      .forEach(curKey => {
        if (curKey !== key) ScriptProps.delete(key)
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68839699/1595451

Answer (score 0):

If you're a business customer, you can now sign up for [Early Access to App Maker](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/apps-script-eap), which includes [Flexible Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#flexible_quotas_early_access).

> Under the flexible quota system, such hard quota limits are removed. Scripts do not stop when they reach a quota limit. Rather, they are delayed until quota becomes available, at which point the script execution resumes. Once quotas begin being used, they are refilled at a regular rate. For reasonable usage, script delays are rare.

Comment: This answer is now obsolete. The linked page is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to exit gracefully from the script, save your progress, create a trigger to start again from where you left off, repeat as many times as necessary and then once finished clean up the trigger and any temporary files.

Here is [a detailed article](https://medium.com/geekculture/bypassing-the-maximum-script-runtime-in-google-apps-script-e510aa9ae6da?sk=ca2b3c4d2fa429e02ba5f81a94d0c780) on this very topic.

Comment: While links to external resources might be helpful, posts should be self-contained. Please add a summary of the linked resource or add the more relevant parts directly into the answer body.

Comment: Another answer is linking to the same external resource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68912519/1595451, posted just a few days after yours.

Answer (score 0):

As many people mentioned, the generic solution to this problem is to execute your method across multiple sessions. I found it to be a common problem that I have a bunch of iterations I need to loop over, and I don't want the hassle of writing/maintaining the [boilerplate of creating new sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608327/35690).

Therefore I created a general solution:

```
/**
 * Executes the given function across multiple sessions to ensure there are no timeouts.
 *
 * See https://stackoverflow.com/a/71089403.
 * 
 * @param {Int} items - The items to iterate over.
 * @param {function(Int)} fn - The function to execute each time. Takes in an item from `items`.
 * @param {String} resumeFunctionName - The name of the function (without arguments) to run between sessions. Typically this is the same name of the function that called this method.
 * @param {Int} maxRunningTimeInSecs - The maximum number of seconds a script should be able to run. After this amount, it will start a new session. Note: This must be set to less than the actual timeout as defined in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas (e.g. 6 minutes), otherwise it can't set up the next call.
 * @param {Int} timeBetweenIterationsInSeconds - The amount of time between iterations of sessions. Note that Google Apps Script won't honor this 100%, as if you choose a 1 second delay, it may actually take a minute or two before it actually executes.
 */
function iterateAcrossSessions(items, fn, resumeFunctionName, maxRunningTimeInSeconds = 5 * 60, timeBetweenIterationsInSeconds = 1) {
  const PROPERTY_NAME = 'iterateAcrossSessions_index';
  let scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  let startTime = (new Date()).getTime();

  let startIndex = parseInt(scriptProperties.getProperty(PROPERTY_NAME));
  if (Number.isNaN(startIndex)) {
    startIndex = 0;
  }

  for (let i = startIndex; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.info(`[iterateAcrossSessions] Executing for i = ${i}.`)
    fn(items[i]);

    let currentTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    let elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;
    let maxRunningTimeInMilliseconds = maxRunningTimeInSeconds * 1000;
    if (maxRunningTimeInMilliseconds <= elapsedTime) {
      let newTime = new Date(currentTime + timeBetweenIterationsInSeconds * 1000);
      console.info(`[iterateAcrossSessions] Creating new session for i = ${i+1} at ${newTime}, since elapsed time was ${elapsedTime}.`);
      scriptProperties.setProperty(PROPERTY_NAME, i+1);
      ScriptApp.newTrigger(resumeFunctionName).timeBased().at(newTime).create();
      return;
    }
  }

  console.log(`[iterateAcrossSessions] Done iterating over items.`);
  // Reset the property here to ensure that the execution loop could be restarted.
  scriptProperties.deleteProperty(PROPERTY_NAME);
}
```

You can now use this pretty easily like so:

```
let ITEMS = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

function execute() {
  iterateAcrossSessions(
    ITEMS,
    (item) => {
      console.log(`Hello world ${item}`);
    }, 
    "execute");
}
```

It'll automatically execute the internal lambda for each value in ITEMS, seamlessly spreading across sessions as needed.

For example, if you use a 0-second maxRunningTime it would run across 4 sessions with the following outputs:

```
[iterateAcrossSessions] Executing for i = 0.
Hello world A
[iterateAcrossSessions] Creating new session for i = 1.
```

```
[iterateAcrossSessions] Executing for i = 1.
Hello world B
[iterateAcrossSessions] Creating new session for i = 2.
```

```
[iterateAcrossSessions] Executing for i = 2.
Hello world C
[iterateAcrossSessions] Creating new session for i = 3.
```

```
[iterateAcrossSessions] Done iterating over items.
```

Comment: It's great to have a workaround here, but there are a lot of similar "answers" around. I don't recall if there is already a good canonical question.