# Google Script to filter out unwanted characters for entire sheet on importrange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So there's a regex I want to run to strip out all non-ascii.
The regex is: [^\x00-\x7F]

Is there a way to do this on the import or do I need to get everything imported and go cell by cell and find the character and replace it with ""?

The function I'm using to import everything is:

```
function createNewSheet(newSheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  yourNewSheet = ss.insertSheet();
  yourNewSheet.setName(newSheetName); 
  yourNewSheet.getRange('A1').setFormula('=query(IMPORTRANGE(\"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=0\", \"Master!A:K\"), \"SELECT Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col11 where Col1 = \'"& \'Select Your Event\'!A3 &"\' Order By Col9, Col10",1)')
  pasteValues(newSheetName);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  yourNewSheet.autoResizeColumns(7,4);
}
```

Comment: Record a macro using the inbuilt find and replace.

Comment: Can I call a macro from google script?

Comment: Yes. Macro is Google script. If you're having troubles, just copy the macro code as script.

Comment: Ah I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get the macro to record any of the Find/Replace activity.  But I figured it out.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution from this answer:
[Google Apps Script for Multiple Find and Replace in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150450/google-apps-script-for-multiple-find-and-replace-in-google-sheets)

I was able to implement the regex I needed this way and scan and replace all the non-ASCII chars in my sheet

```
function runReplaceInSheet(newSheetName){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(newSheetName);
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  // Search for all non-ASCII values and just replace them with nothing
  regex = new RegExp ('[^\x00-\x7F]', 'gi');
  replaceInSheet(values, regex, "");

  // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```