# How to keep the date from turning into a String when using a Google Apps Script in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have used a Script posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150450/google-apps-script-for-multiple-find-and-replace-in-google-sheets) in a large Google Spreadsheet, to replace a String with a Number.

It works great, but the problem is, the **date gets turned into a String**.

I believe that the problem is the method `toString()`, but I couldn't find any alternative to make the code work.

=> Does anyone have an idea to avoid this problem?

Script

```html
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  // Replace  
  replaceInSheet(values, 'datateam', '42007860');

  
  // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to replace values of Spreadsheet.

  - In your script, you want to replace from `datateam` to `42007860`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `getDisplayValues()` is used instead of `getValues()`.

#### Modified script

Please modify your script as follows. In this modification, the function of `runReplaceInSheet()` is modified.

```
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); // Modified

  // Replace  
  replaceInSheet(values, 'datateam', '42007860');


  // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, TextFinder is used instead of `replaceInSheet()` and `setValues()`.

#### Modified script

Please modify your script as follows. In this modification, the function of `runReplaceInSheet()` is modified. And also, in this modification, `replaceInSheet` is not used.

```
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet3");
  sheet.createTextFinder('datateam').replaceAllWith('42007860'); // Added
}
```

### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValues())
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @AlejandroRod Thank you for replying. If your issue was still not resolved, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the template, your actual XLS file.
Set the type of the cells before entering the data.
I assume this might be your problem not your actual code.
This is in the Home tab.

[image]