# Match Entire Cell for Multiple Find and Replace in Google Sheets via Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

First question here - I'm trying to use the Multiple Find and Replace in Google App Scripts for Google Sheets from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150450/google-apps-script-for-multiple-find-and-replace-in-google-sheets?newreg=1df907c9f09f4ff09521543e1637ff44), however, I need to do an exact match on the cell. I did some research and see mentions of the class TextFinder and method matchExactCell, but I am stumped on where to add it.

When the script is run multiple times, then the first name in the replace is appended multiple times so the replaced cell reads: "John John John Smith" if script is run 3 times.

Any recommendations are appreciated! Thanks!

```
function runReplaceInSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  //  get the current data range values as an array
  //  Fewer calls to access the sheet -> lower overhead 
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();  

  // Replace Names
  replaceInSheet(values, 'Smith', 'John Smith');
  replaceInSheet(values, 'Doe', 'Jane Doe');

  // Write all updated values to the sheet, at once
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}

function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this little modification that does not use the function "replace" but compares the whole value with "replace_to" and returns "replace_with" if it's equal or "original_values" if it's not:

```
function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
      if(original_value == to_replace) {return replace_with}
      else {return original_value};
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As another approach, from `I did some research and see mentions of the class TextFinder and method matchExactCell, but I am stumped on where to add it.`, if you want to use TextFinder, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var obj = [
    { find: "Smith", replacement: "John Smith" },
    { find: "Doe", replacement: "Jane Doe" }
  ];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  obj.forEach(({ find, replacement }) => range.createTextFinder(find).matchEntireCell(true).replaceAllWith(replacement));
}
```

- Although the process cost of TextFinder is low, in this case, the replacement is run in a loop. If you want to reduce the process cost more, how about the following sample script? In this sample, Sheets API is used. By this, the process cost is lower a little than that of the above. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

  ```js
  function sample2() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheetId = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getSheetId();
    var obj = [
      { find: "Smith", replacement: "John Smith" },
      { find: "Doe", replacement: "Jane Doe" }
    ];
    var requests = obj.map(({ find, replacement }) => ({ findReplace: { find, replacement, range: { sheetId }, matchEntireCell: true } }));
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
  }
  ```

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createtextfinderfindtext)
- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [FindReplaceRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#findreplacerequest)