# Define sheet range as being on separate sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

currently using this Google Apps script to populate formulas in same row as edits are made, but I'd like to see it populating cells on a different sheet within the same file.

It seems like I need to define `destrange` as being the next empty row on a separate destination sheet but I"m not sure how to do that.

```
function onEdit(e){
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = e.range;
var sheet = range.getSheet()
var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Apps")
var sheetName = sheet.getName()
if(sheetName != "Form"){
   return                            //exit function
}  
var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
if (columnOfCellEdited === 1) 
 var range2 = range.getRow();
 var destrange = newSheet.getLastRow()
 sheet = newSheet
     // adds the formulas
     var cell = sheet.getRange("C" + destrange);
  cell.setFormula('=Form!$B' + destrange);
     var cell = sheet.getRange("D" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=Form!$C' + destrange);
     var cell = sheet.getRange("E" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=Form!$D' + destrange);
     var cell = sheet.getRange("F" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=Form!$E' + destrange);
     var cell = sheet.getRange("G" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=Form!$F' + destrange);
     var cell = sheet.getRange("H" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=Form!$G' + destrange);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to set the sheet variable to the sheet you want to write in

For example: In the code below:

```
var sheet = range.getSheet()
```

to get a sheet named "Sheet2" you would do this

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
```

To get an empty row on the new sheet, you will do the following

```
 var destRange = sheet.getLastRow()+1
```

Document on getSheetByName can be [found here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetName())

Also note, your approach of editing one cell at a time is not the most efficient approach 
Have look at this question to understand how to a batch update [Google app script timeout ~ 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/google-app-script-timeout-5-minutes)

Edit:

Final code:

```
function onEdit(e){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var range = e.range;
    var sheet = range.getSheet()
    var newSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
    var sheetName = sheet.getName()
    if(sheetName != "Form Responses"){
       return                            //exit function
    }  
    var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
    if (columnOfCellEdited === 1) 
     var range2 = range.getRow();
     var destrange = newSheet.getLastRow()
     sheet = newSheet
     // adds the formulas
     var cell = sheet.getRange("C" + destrange);
  cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH(":",$B' + destrange +')+1,SEARCH(",",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH(":",$B' + destrange +')-1),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("D" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B' + destrange +',FIND("$",B' + destrange +'),LEN(B' + destrange +'))," ",REPT(" ",100)),100)),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("E" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("exceed",$B' + destrange +')+7,SEARCH("%",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("exceed",$B' + destrange +')-6),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("F" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("due",$B' + destrange +')+3,SEARCH(";",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("due",$B' + destrange +')-3),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("G" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("held on",$B' + destrange +')+7,SEARCH(". Lottery",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("held on",$B' + destrange +')-7),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
     var cell = sheet.getRange("H" + destrange);
     cell.setFormula('=IFERROR(MID($B' + destrange +',SEARCH("posted by",$B' + destrange +')+9,SEARCH(". ",$B' + destrange +')-SEARCH("",$B' + destrange +')-167),HYPERLINK("https://housing.sfgov.org/listings","See Housing Portal"))');
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I haven't been having any timeout issues with this script. At least not yet. Thanks for the suggestions. What would the final script look like?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I need to do some more work on the script. What I'm trying to do is: anytime there's a form submission, transfer data from the new row, taking from Columns B-G in `Form Responses` and sending to the first blank row of `Sheet 2`.

Comment: onedit doesn't trigger when a form response is submitted to the sheet. You will have to use from submit trigger

Answer (score 1):

@minky_boodle the triggers can be set by going to: [image]

then set it:
[image]

Comment: Still not quite getting what I'm looking for. Made some edits to original post above, hoping to get this worked out before Monday afternoon deadline