# timing out due to GDrive conversion

Tags: google-apps-script, timeout, connection-timeout, server-error

I have numerous scripts in numerous containers and sheets that have been timing out since the GDrive crash in the earlier part of September.  What is the best way to have GCloud engineering take a look at the issue?  I have gotten nowhere with the Api team and regular support.

Comment: I can understand the frustration, but without a piece of code to analyze we cannot help you. Maybe together we can help you, but you need to do the first step ;)

Comment: @MatteoRagni is correct, you should probably share your code to pin point reason why you are encountering the issue. You should probably need to optimize your code so that you won't be hitting the execution quota for Google Apps Script. Try following this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29800759/5995040), this may provide key details about execution timeout for Apps Script. The [tutorial](https://ctrlq.org/code/20016-maximum-execution-time-limit) - "Prevent Google Scripts from Exceeding the Maximum Execution Time Limit" should also give you a workaround for the issue.