# How to Reduce Google App Script Service Calls

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script here renames the sheetnames with the value in A1. I manage a school database with over 150 sheets. The script is throwing a maximum time execution timeout error. I have read on the forums here that you can reduce service calls. This here [Google app script timeout ~ 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/google-app-script-timeout-5-minutes?noredirect=1&lq=1) looks like a solution but I can't in the life of me wrap my head around what's going on.

I should probably mention that I am a complete noob and your help will be of immense help.

```
function onEdit() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

// Array holding the names of the sheets to exclude from the execution
var exclude ="Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet3","Article","Frontpage","Logos","Sheet4","Sheet5","Sheet6","Sheet10"];

for(var s=10;s<allsheets.length;s++) {
var sheet = allsheets[s];
var oldName = sheet.getName();
var newName = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
if (newName.toString().length>0 && newName !== oldName) {
sheet.setName(newName);

// Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue;
}

} // end of loop

} // end of function
```

Kindly help me reduce the number of service calls the script is making or a faster way to avoid the timeout error.

//Updated Script

//Sample code below generating error missing ) after condition

```
function testArray() {
    var arr = ["Sh1","Sh2","Sh3","Sh4","Sh5","Sh6","Sh7","Sh8","Sh9","Sh10"];  //etc etc
    var res = [];

    arr.forEach(function (element,index) {
        if(index>9) {
            var sheet = allsheets[s];
            var oldName = sheet.getName();
            var newName = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue(); 

            if (newName.toString().length>0 && newName !== oldName) {
                sheet.setName(newName); // Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet. 
                if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1}) continue; //iterable code goes here; 
            }
        // }
     }); 
}
```

Comment: Could you please include your execution transcript so that we can see what's taking the most time? This can be viewed by running the script then going to `View > Execution transcript`.

Comment: Hi, `[19-05-28 08:12:42:455 PDT] Range.getValue() [2.157 seconds]` there are many of this so I didn't want to post the entire log here because this only is repeating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, get rid of unnecessary calls - did you consider the `splice()` part of my answer to your previous question?

```
allsheets.splice(0,10); //0-based start and end indexes;
```

If excluded sheet names can be encountered anywhere, keep your `exclude` Array and `if` statement (btw, there seems to be a typo in your sample - the `Array` declaration misses an opening bracket).

Regardless of how you exclude your first 10 sheets, the call to stop iteration becomes overkill as you invoke `getName()` method `allsheets.length` times (thus, 150 unnecessary method calls) - reference the `newName` variable instead.

You can further reduce calls by checking for the condition before calling the `setName()` method (assuming you do not want to do anything is new name is in `exclude` Array).

Then, use the `for` loop to do the same manipulations (note that in case the `Array` is filtered using `splice()`, index `s` should be `0`):

```
for(var s=10; s<allsheets.length; s++) {
  var sheet = allsheets[s];
  var oldName = sheet.getName();
  var newName = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();

  //this reduces setName() calls if you don't need to set reserved names;
  if(exclude.indexOf(newName)!==-1) { continue; }

  if (newName.toString().length>0 && newName !== oldName) {
    sheet.setName(newName);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a `forEach` to make manipulations you want. This is how the whole function will look like using `splice()` and `forEach()`:

```
function testArray() { 

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var arr = ss.getSheets();

  arr.splice(0,10); //removes first 10 Sheets from Array;

  var exclude = []; //fill with unchangeable names;

  arr.forEach(function (sheet,index) { //iterates over Array of Sheets;

      var oldName = sheet.getName(); 
      var newName = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue(); 

      if(newName.toString().length>0 && newName!==oldName) { 

        //Move to next iteration if new name should be excluded;
        if(exclude.indexOf(newName)===-1) {
          sheet.setName(newName); //set name otherwise;
        }

      }

  }); // end of loop 

} // end of function
```

Comment: This answer assumes that you want to exclude first ten sheet name, not the *ten sheet names from the Array provided* - judging from your answer, I might be wrong here, please, let me know if this is the case, I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: Just in case, updated the answer to be solution-independed, will keep looking if it can be optimized further.

Comment: About the missing bracket that's a typo. I was testing the two options for excluding the first 10 sheets. They are the same ones I listed there so I should remove the list and let the script check for the first 10 and exclude them.

Comment: Hi Oleg, getting this error when i run the script above `ReferenceError: "allsheets" is not defined. (line 1, file "Code")`

Comment: Hi! You should call this method (if we are talking about `splice()` here) only after you got your sheets written into a `allsheets` variable - judging from the error, you tried to invoke it globally on the first line, whereas you should call it in-function after calling `ss.getSheets()`

Comment: I have tried but each time I get an error - `Continue must be inside loop. (line 48, file "Code")` Looks like this is beyond my reach. Here is what I did, I listed all sheets in an array then added the iteration code after the `if(index>9) {
      res.push(element); //push to test Array` Any pointers or a simplified example. Sorry that I have to ask again.

Comment: @DanstanOngubo, please, update your question with all the code that you currently have, looks like there is a closure problem (the error message states that continue is outside the loop, which means that most likely you accidentally closed the loop before invoking the `if` statement. No worries!

Comment: `function testArray() {

  var arr = ["Sh1","Sh2","Sh3","Sh4","Sh5","Sh6","Sh7","Sh8","Sh9","Sh10"];//etc etc

  var res = [];

  arr.forEach(function (element,index) {

    if(index>9) {
  
var sheet = allsheets[s];
var oldName = sheet.getName();
var newName = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
if (newName.toString().length>0 && newName !== oldName) {
sheet.setName(newName);

// Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1) continue;
      //iterable code goes here;
    }

  });


}`

Comment: Thanks! Yep, there is a missing `}` right before the `)` - there should be three of curly brackets to properly close one of the `if` statements.

Comment: `//...truncating for character count
  var res = [];

  arr.forEach(function (element,index) {

    if(index>9) {
  
var sheet = allsheets[s];
var oldName = sheet.getName();
var newName = sheet.getRange(1,1).getValue();
if (newName.toString().length>0 && newName !== oldName) {
sheet.setName(newName);

 // Stop iteration execution if the condition is met.
  if(exclude.indexOf(sheet.getName())==-1}) continue;
  
  }

  } // end of loop
} // end of function`  Sorry, Missing ) after condition. I have tried adding the bracket after but it won't work. What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, simply update your question with this code (for example, after the sample code) - posting it in comments makes it hard to parse and read (you can edit your posts as much as you want to)

Comment: Also, I noticed that you are trying to use continue inside a forEach loop, this should not be used here (as forEach uses a callback function, not a proper loop) - I updated my answer with an example of the test function you are trying to build - please, do not forget to actually fetch sheets at the start

Comment: Your final test script worked! I thank you from the bottom of my heart! Good luck buddy.

Comment: My pleasure! Take a look at the MDN [documentation on Array class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) when you have time (and their JS doc in gerenal - it greatly helped me when I started). And to you!