# Is there any difference in getting value in a variable using getValue and array value position (GAS)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Say I have an integer value "45,678.25" in cell A10 in google sheet.
Initially, I will use below command to assign the value in A10 into a variable:
Method1:
`var myitem=sheet.getRange(10,1).getValue();`

Then I noticed that I could also do the same with below command:
Method2:

```
var sheetdata=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var myitem=sheetdata[9][0];
```

I plan to change all from method 1 (getValue) to method 2 (calling by value position in DataRange) in all of my custom functions as I feel it looks tidier. But is it safe to do so? Will there be any impact on the end result/output?

I've created sampling test code with the output to show that there IS a significant impact to the output.

Sampling Code with Method 1 :

```
function checker(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('mystaff'),
  staffdata=ss.getDataRange().getValues(),
  lastrow=ss.getLastRow(),
  staffID=ss.getRange(lastrow,1).getValue(),
  name=ss.getRange(lastrow,4).getValue(); // Marlina
  
    ss.getRange(lastrow,2).setFormula('=COUNTIF($D1:D'+lastrow+',D'+lastrow+')') // 2
    ss.getRange("mystaff!B"+lastrow+":B"+lastrow).copyTo(ss.getRange("mystaff!B"+lastrow), {contentsOnly: true});
    
//Method 1
    var RFQ=ss.getRange(lastrow,2).getValue();
    console.log("RFQ by getValue:"+RFQ); // 2
//end of Method 1
  
    if(staffID==""){
    if(RFQ>1){
       staffID=name.slice(0,3).toUpperCase();
      console.log("moreRFQ :"+RFQ);
      staffID=staffID+'('+RFQ+')';
      Logger.log("newstaffID : "+staffID);
    }else{
    staffID=name.slice(3,5).toUpperCase();
        console.log("firstRFQ :"+RFQ);
        staffID=staffID+'('+RFQ+')';
        Logger.log("newstaffID : "+staffID);
        }
    }
    ss.getRange(lastrow,1).setValue(staffID); // output : MAR(2)
}
```

Sampling Code with Method 2:

```
function checker(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('mystaff'),
  staffdata=ss.getDataRange().getValues(),
  lastrow=ss.getLastRow(),
  staffID=ss.getRange(lastrow,1).getValue(),
  name=ss.getRange(lastrow,4).getValue(); // Marlina
  
    ss.getRange(lastrow,2).setFormula('=COUNTIF($D1:D'+lastrow+',D'+lastrow+')') // 2
    ss.getRange("mystaff!B"+lastrow+":B"+lastrow).copyTo(ss.getRange("mystaff!B"+lastrow), {contentsOnly: true});
   
//Method 2
    var RFQ=staffdata[lastrow-1][1];
    console.log("RFQ by array:"+RFQ); // blank
//end of Method 2
  
    if(staffID==""){
    if(RFQ>1){
       staffID=name.slice(0,3).toUpperCase();
      console.log("moreRFQ :"+RFQ);
      staffID=staffID+'('+RFQ+')';
      Logger.log("newstaffID : "+staffID);
    }else{
    staffID=name.slice(3,5).toUpperCase();
        console.log("firstRFQ :"+RFQ);
        staffID=staffID+'('+RFQ+')';
        Logger.log("newstaffID : "+staffID);
        }
    }
    ss.getRange(lastrow,1).setValue(staffID); // output : LI()
}
```

The different output is literally caused by the different subfunction it runs based on the IF..ELSE result, although the input source is the same. I'm so curious of why this could happen? Appreciate some logic explanation. Thanks.

Comment: if your only getting one value the code is generally simpler and I suspect faster but I'm no sure.  You can test that for yourself.  The key is to realize that if your going after a lot of values putting them in an array to process them is a lot faster.  So positiioning them wisely in the sheet can really accelerate the performance of your script.   But you can test this for yourself in any given situation.

Comment: Why don't you find the execution time between the two approaches for your specific test case to see which method suits you the best ?

Comment: Well,faster process would be a bonus but I am more concern if it would impact the end result. I just noticed that in one of my custom functions, when I used method 2, when I put console.log down below the command, the value exists inconsistently in the variable when I test run multiple times and that led to inconsistent output. I wonder why but this doesn't happen when I used method 1.

Comment: Many people misunderstand customs functions. Please add a [mcve] to better understand what are you asking and your concerns.

Comment: Besides acceleration GAS has the limitation how many `getValue()` you can perform per second. So, if you process a big table with many cells it makes perfect sense to get them in one fell swoop.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604878/is-setvalues-slower-than-setvalue) post.

Comment: I think that post just purely wanna have another alternative to setValue faster than what already has in place and wants to know the speed variance between the setValue and setValues @ziganotschka . I think that's not the answer I'm looking for with this question.thx anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to do so and there's no impact on the end result or output.

Performance wise, when dealing with large data, getting all the data in one shot is [the recommended best practice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations). However, if you only need  specific ranges, take only the  range that encompasses all the ranges you need and not all dataRange. If you need, A1, C1 and B5, You can take, `getRange("A1:C5").getValues()` and index into the resulting array accordingly.

---

Based on the updated code,  There is another difference between the two `checker` functions: The confounding variable here is Time.

In method 1,

```
//Bunch of operations affecting the B column of range
var RFQ=ss.getRange(lastrow,2).getValue();
console.log("RFQ by getValue:"+RFQ); // 2
```

`RFQ` Value is retrieved after doing a bunch of other operations.

In method 2,

```
staffdata=ss.getDataRange().getValues(),
//Bunch of operations affecting Col B of last row
//Method 2
var RFQ=staffdata[lastrow-1][1];
```

`staffdata` values are retrieved before any changes are made to sheet.

To  remove the confounding variable and to make both tests relatable, use `getValues()` in method2 at the same time/line in `getValue()` of method1.

```
//Bunch of operations affecting Col B of last row
//Method 2
const staffdata = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
const RFQ=staffdata[lastrow-1][1];
```

Alternatively, to make the tests unbiased,

```
var RFQ=ss.getRange(lastrow,2).getValue();// moved up
//Bunch of operations affecting the B column of range
console.log("RFQ by getValue:"+RFQ); // 2
```

Comment: After adding the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , I'm afraid I have to disagree with you, @TheMaster .

Comment: Ok, seems like I have to declare the DataRange repeatedly each time I run an operation towards the previous value else the variable RFQ will not be updated. If that's the case Method 2 will only be adding more lines of codes rather than decreasing it. :(

Comment: the getValue command will give me the latest value after the operation because it is being called after the range is updated.

Comment: now I understood clearly why it made the difference and I think with this finding, I think it is safer to stick to Method 1. Thanks a lot for taking the time to clarify this to me, @TheMaster . Really appreciate it very much!

Comment: @dell *I think it is safer to stick to Method 1.* Why?

Comment: @dell In both cases, if `getValue` or `getValues` are used at the same time, the result is the same. Read best practices.

Comment: I supposed I should add 'tidier' along with 'safer' in my comment on sticking to Method 1.

Comment: Tidier because I don't have to keep on coding 2 lines (or a long code line) each time I wanna call the value after each operation (Method 2 needs me to declare DataRange first). Safer for especially someone who is often absentminded as myself. :D If I forgot to declare the DataRange first (even to just some or maybe just 1 subfunction) before calling back the value aft each operation, it would affect the output and troubleshooting to find the culprit is really time consuming.

Comment: I guess we should emphasize the context getValues in here is focusing getDataRange.getValues and not getRange.getValues .

Comment: @dell Method2 is cleaner and faster. If you want it 1 line, use `ss.getDataRange().getValues()[lastrow-1][1]`. Also, Don't mix formulas and scripts. In fact, Don't touch the spreadsheet after getting values. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57836700/ Practice arrays. Don't do safer.  Take risks as the rewards are worth the risk.

Comment: ouh, I just realized this `ss.getDataRange().getValues()[lastrow-1][1]` is one way to do the same in one line and definitely cleaner and faster. Thanks a lot, @TheMaster ! Now I can proceed changing in all my functions with confidence. Yeay!

Comment: @dell Don't look at just changing the lines. Change your thought process entirely.

Comment: still learning as I'm entirely just 3months+ exploring this GAS which also means learning Javascript and HTML for email altogether.

Comment: @dell I'm sure you are learning. That's why I'm driving you to learn it  right. It's better than learning it wrong, erasing what you learnt previously and learning it right again.  You'll do well, if you value what I said and read up and practice all the links.

Comment: Thanks, @TheMaster . Wise thought indeed. ;)