# Is there a way to stop a COUNTIF function after the value changes from TRUE to FALSE in google spreadsheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, countif

I have a row of tick boxes and I need to count the most recent successive `TRUE` values. So it should start counting when the first `TRUE` appears and stop when it changes to `FALSE`, ignoring anything that comes after that.

Right now I have a script doing that, but since I have a lot of entries, it takes a long time to run and stops after 6min without finishing everything.

```
for(var j=3;j<lastRow;j++){
    count = 0;
    for (var k=stupac-1;k>2;k--){
      if (range.getCell(j,k).getValue() == true){
        count++;
      }
      else if ((range.getCell(j,k).isChecked() == false)&&(count>0)){
        break;
      }
    }
    range.getCell(j,stupac).setValue(count);
  }
```

I thought the best way would be to stop the COUNTIF when the value changes, but have had no luck trying to get that working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/google-app-script-timeout-5-minutes

Comment: @Calculuswhiz nope, the whole script is a bit longer and doesn't affect this part
also, its a WIP, so I forgot to update that one bit, thanks for reminding me

Comment: @TheMaster not really, I don't want it to run constantly, but I might use something from that solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution which seems pretty fast. Your approach iterates over each **cell** which is not efficient especially when the search space is large. The following approach iterates over the **rows** in the specified `data` range.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  const data = sh.getRange('A3:G'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const counts = [];
  
  data.forEach(row=>{                  
               let t_index = row.indexOf(true);             
               let cutRow = t_index > -1 ? row.slice(t_index, row.length+1) : [];        
               let f_index = cutRow.indexOf(false);
               let ct = f_index > -1 ? f_index : cutRow.length;
               counts.push([ct]);                 
               });           
                
sh.getRange(3,8,counts.length,counts[0].length).setValues(counts);
                             
}
```

Please adjust the data ranges according to your needs.

The solution here matches the following file:

[image: example]

Please make sure that you have enabled [V8 Runtime](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime).