# Google Scripts - How can I break my code into segments due to avoid the exceeding maximum run-time issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

big noob here with javascript, appreciate any help.

I have a script that will likely run about 30 minutes - it loops through a bunch of stock tickers on one sheet (queries using GOOGLEFINANCE) and copies the results to a master data sheet.

```
function loop() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var historical = ss.getSheetByName('Historical');
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var tickers = ss.getSheetByName('Tickers').getRange('B2:B607').getValues();
  var copyRange = historical.getRange(12, 1, historical.getLastRow()-11, 7);
  for (var i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++) {
    historical.getRange('C2').setValue(tickers[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    if (historical.getRange('C7').getValue() == 'YES') {
      data.getRange(data.getLastRow()+1, 1,historical.getLastRow()-11,7).setValues(copyRange.getValues()); 
    }
  }
}
```

The sleep above is so that the formulas have a chance to refresh.

I found the following code snippet which I think is the answer from (https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608327)

```
function runMe() {
  var startTime= (new Date()).getTime();
  
  //do some work here
  
  var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var startRow= scriptProperties.getProperty('start_row');
  for(var ii = startRow; ii <= size; ii++) {
    var currTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    if(currTime - startTime >= MAX_RUNNING_TIME) {
      scriptProperties.setProperty("start_row", ii);
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("runMe")
               .timeBased()
               .at(new Date(currTime+REASONABLE_TIME_TO_WAIT))
               .create();
      break;
    } else {
      doSomeWork();
    }
  }
  
  //do some more work here
  
}
```

But I can't figure out how to integrate the two... how do I merge these two together?
Or is there a better solution? Open to other ideas on how to approach.

Any advice appreciated. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of processing all the tickers (`B2:B607`) in a single execution you have to process them in batches. One way to do this is by parametrizing your loop function, i.e. instead of `getRange(A1Notation)` you might use `getRange(row,column,numRows,numColumns)` setting  `row` and `numRows` as function parameters.

```
function loop(start, howMany) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var historical = ss.getSheetByName('Historical');
  var data = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var tickers = ss.getSheetByName('Tickers').getRange(start,2,howMany,1).getValues();
  var copyRange = historical.getRange(12, 1, historical.getLastRow()-11, 7);
  for (var i = 0; i < tickers.length; i++) {
    historical.getRange('C2').setValue(tickers[i][0]);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    if (historical.getRange('C7').getValue() == 'YES') {
      data.getRange(data.getLastRow()+1, 1,historical.getLastRow()-11,7).setValues(copyRange.getValues()); 
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't understand how the `runMe` function works, then you might find better to  call the above function in following way:

```
function batch1(){
  loop(2, 304);
}

function batch2(){
  loop(305, 607 - 304);
}
```

1. Run `batch1`
2. Wait it to finish
3. Run `batch2`

(you might have to use smallers howMany values and more `batchN` functions)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks for taking the time to answer. I've implemented this and assigned a trigger to launch these batches one after the other. Works great!  I also noticed you removed the Sleep timer and it still works (so that's an added bonus as even faster now so can have larger batches).