# Avoid Maximum Execution Time Limit in Google Apps to existing code

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this code that lists all files and folders within a specific google drive folder by the folder ID, however, I need to avoid the "Maximum Execution Time Limit" error because the directory I'm scrapping contains a lot of files and folders

How can I let my script continue from the last crawled files (last row) instead of starting from the beginning after getting the error?

```
 function onOpen() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('List Files/Folders')
    .addItem('List All Files and Folders', 'listFilesAndFolders')
    .addToUi();
};

function listFilesAndFolders(){
  var folderId = Browser.inputBox('Enter folder ID', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if (folderId === "") {
    Browser.msgBox('Folder ID is invalid');
    return;
  }
  getFolderTree(folderId, true); 
};

// Get Folder Tree
function getFolderTree(folderId, listAll) {
  try {
    // Get folder by id
    var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
    
    // Initialise the sheet
    var file, data, sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.clear();
    sheet.appendRow(["Full Path", "Name","Type" ,"Date", "URL", "Last Updated", "Description", "Size","Owner Email"]);
    
    // Get files and folders
    getChildFolders(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder, data, sheet, listAll);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }
};

// Get the list of files and folders and their metadata in recursive mode
function getChildFolders(parentName, parent, data, sheet, listAll) {
  var childFolders = parent.getFolders();
 
  // List folders inside the folder
  while (childFolders.hasNext()) {
    var childFolder = childFolders.next();
    var folderId = childFolder.getId();
    data = [ 
      parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(),
      childFolder.getName(),
      "Folder",
      childFolder.getDateCreated(),
      childFolder.getUrl(),
      childFolder.getLastUpdated(),
      childFolder.getDescription(),
      childFolder.getSize()/1024,
      childFolder.getOwner().getEmail()
    ];
    // Write
    sheet.appendRow(data);
    
    // List files inside the folder
    var files = childFolder.getFiles();
    while (listAll & files.hasNext()) {
      var childFile = files.next();
      data = [ 
        parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName() + "/" + childFile.getName(),
        childFile.getName(),
        "Files",
        childFile.getDateCreated(),
        childFile.getUrl(),
        childFile.getLastUpdated(),
        childFile.getDescription(),
        childFile.getSize()/1024,
        childFile.getOwner().getEmail(),
      ];
      // Write
      sheet.appendRow(data);
    }
    // Recursive call of the subfolder
    getChildFolders(parentName + "/" + childFolder.getName(), childFolder, data, sheet, listAll);  
  }
};
```

Comment: I think that in your script, `appendRow` is used in the loop. In this case, the process cost will become high. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. But, before that is modified, can I ask you about the maximum number of files in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

The limit for any app script is around 6 minutes. You would need to find a way to either split it or bypass the runtime.

There has been an excellent discussion on how to properly log the executions and also how to manage it with sample codes that could be useful as a reference on how to rebuild the code. As it is working as expected.

- [Google app script timeout ~ 5 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/google-app-script-timeout-5-minutes#tab-top)

By the way some of the responses mentioned appmaker, however that one is deprecated.