# Google Apps Script - Exception: Service timed out: Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First off, apologies if this is a poorly written post as this is my first time asking a question to SO.

I am working on a project that imports several different gCals and combines them into one sheet, then recreates them in a master combined calendar. This sheet will ultimately also have the ability to update event info in their respective calendars and thus on the combined calendar as well. However, I am running into this error on about 40% of my time based trigger executions for a function that imports both of the calendars, then recreates the events on the combined calendar and lastly logs the event creations by moving data from one sheet to another:  "Exception: Service timed out: Spreadsheets".

I am trying to figure out any poorly optimized code (I am sure there is a lot, as I am not a developer and have just been piecing together my knowledge as I go), or if there are any changes I can make to the spreadsheet to speed up the processing, as the sheet moves very sluggish after successful execution, though that I believe is just due to the large amount of vlookups used in the sheet to reference different data sources.

Below is the code for importing the 2 calendars.

```
// Calendar 1 Import to sheets
function cal1SortSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cal1 Calendar Import");
  spreadsheet.sort(5, true);
};

function cal1_export_gcal_to_gsheet(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Backend");
var date1 = sheet.getRange('B6').getValue();
var date2 = sheet.getRange('B7').getValue();
var calendarId = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(date1), new Date(date2));

var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cal1 Calendar Import");
// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event","Event ID"]]
var range = sheet2.getRange(1,1,1,15);
range.setValues(header);

console.log('Cal1 start loop')
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calulated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';

var details=[[calendarId,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(),events[i].getId()]];
var range=sheet2.getRange(row,1,1,15);
range.setValues(details).sort(9);
}

var cell=sheet2.getRange(row,7);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
cell.setNumberFormat('.00');

//sort values by event start
Cal1SortSheet();
console.log('Cal1 start sort')

}

function cal2SortSheet() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cal1 Calendar Import");
  spreadsheet.sort(5, true);
};

// Calendar 2 Import to sheets
function cal2_export_gcal_to_gsheet(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Backend");
var date1 = sheet.getRange('B6').getValue();
var date2 = sheet.getRange('B7').getValue();
var calendarId = sheet.getRange('B3').getValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(date1), new Date(date2));

var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cal2 Calendar Import");
// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event","Event ID"]]
var range = sheet2.getRange(1,1,1,15);
range.setValues(header);

console.log('Cal2 start loop')
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calculated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';

var details=[[calendarId,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(),events[i].getId()]];
var range=sheet2.getRange(row,1,1,15);
range.setValues(details).sort(9);
}

var cell=sheet2.getRange(row,7);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
cell.setNumberFormat('.00');

//sort values by event start
Cal2SortSheet();
console.log('Cal2 start sort')

}

function importBoth() {
  cal1_export_gcal_to_gsheet()
  cal2_export_gcal_to_gsheet()
}
```

Then here is the code for importing the combined calendar, to reference which events already exist vs which events are new (this is done within the spreadsheet with vlookups)

```
// Combined calendar Import to sheets
function combined_export_gcal_to_gsheet(){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Backend");
var date1 = sheet.getRange('B6').getValue();
var date2 = sheet.getRange('B7').getValue();
var calendarId = sheet.getRange('B1').getValue();
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(date1), new Date(date2));

var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Combined Schedule Import");
// Create a header record on the current spreadsheet in cells A1:N1 - Match the number of entries in the "header=" to the last parameter
// of the getRange entry below
var header = [["Calendar Address", "Event Title", "Event Description", "Event Location", "Event Start", "Event End", "Calculated Duration", "Visibility", "Date Created", "Last Updated", "MyStatus", "Created By", "All Day Event", "Recurring Event","Event ID"]]
var range = sheet2.getRange(1,1,1,15);
range.setValues(header);

console.log('combined start loop')    
// Loop through all calendar events found and write them out starting on calculated ROW 2 (i+2)
for (var i=0;i<events.length;i++) {
var row=i+2;
var myformula_placeholder = '';


var details=[[calendarId,events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), myformula_placeholder, ('' + events[i].getVisibility()), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated(), events[i].getMyStatus(), events[i].getCreators(), events[i].isAllDayEvent(), events[i].isRecurringEvent(),events[i].getId()]];
var range=sheet2.getRange(row,1,1,15);
range.setValues(details).sort(9);
}
var cell=sheet2.getRange(row,7);
cell.setFormula('=(HOUR(F' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(F' +row+ ')/60))-(HOUR(E' +row+ ')+(MINUTE(E' +row+ ')/60))');
cell.setNumberFormat('.00');

//sort values by event start
CombinedSortSheet();
console.log('combined start sort')  


}
```

And lastly, here is the code that creates events on the combined calendar by referencing a spreadsheet that pulls in both the calendar imports. After creation, the events are then logged in 2 respective sheets in their respective "archives".

```
function CombinedScheduleru24() {
  console.log('combined sched u24 start')
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Combined Scheduler u24");
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('C1').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var count = spreadsheet.getRange("B3:F"+lr+"").getValues();
  for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {
          var shift = count[x];
      var summary = shift[0];
      var startTime = new Date(shift[1]);
      var endTime = new Date(shift[2]);
      var guests = shift[3];
      var description = shift[4];
      var location = shift[5];
     var event = {
         'location': location,
         'description': description,
         'guests':guests +',',
         'sendInvites': 'True',
}
     try {
      eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event)
} catch(error) {
console.log(error.message, error.stack);
break;
}
console.log('combined sched u24 end')
}
} 

function CombinedSchedulerov24() {
  console.log('combined sched ov24 start')
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Combined Scheduler 24up");
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange('C1').getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  var lr = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
  var count = spreadsheet.getRange("B3:F"+lr+"").getValues();
  
  for (x=0; x<count.length; x++) {
          var shift = count[x];
      var summary = shift[0];
      var startTime = new Date(shift[1]);
      var endTime = new Date(shift[2]);
      var guests = shift[3];
      var description = shift[4];
      var location = shift[5];
     var event = {
         'location': location,
         'description': description,
         'guests':guests +',',
         'sendInvites': 'True',
}
     try {
  eventCal.createAllDayEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event)
} catch(error) {
console.log(error.message, error.stack);
break;
}
console.log('combined sched ov24 end')
}
} 

function MoveDataCSu24() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Combined Schedule Logger u 24hrs");
var appendSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Combined Schedule Archive");
var values = activeSheet.getRange("Combined Schedule Logger u 24hrs!A2:" + activeSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
values = values.filter(e=>e[0]); //gets rid of blank rows. filters based on the first column (index 0).
appendSheet.getRange(appendSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}

function MoveDataCSov24() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Combined Schedule Logger 24up");
var appendSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Combined Schedule Archive");
var values = activeSheet.getRange("Combined Schedule Logger 24up!A2:" + activeSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
values = values.filter(e=>e[0]); //gets rid of blank rows. filters based on the first column (index 0).
appendSheet.getRange(appendSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}

function CombinedSchedulerALL() {
  CombinedScheduleru24()
  CombinedSchedulerov24()
  MoveDataCSu24()
  MoveDataCSov24()
}
```

So the final function that calls all this for the trigger looks like this:

```
function ImportAndCombinedSchedule() {
  importBoth()
  CombinedSchedulerALL()
  combined_export_gcal_to_gsheet()
}
```

I have tried splitting the spreadsheet computation up by using other projects and importing ranges to the master sheet, as well as cutting down on any extra cells that I can. However, the issue still persists.

I realize this is probably very poorly executed, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

## SUGGESTION

> **Note:** Stack Overflow community members do not offer coding services. Please utilize this answer as a reference guide while working on your actual project.

In my understanding of your post, you are having problems in running your script in a time based trigger execution as most of the time it produces `Exception: Service timed out: Spreadsheets` error.

Firstly, please note that triggers have more limitations compared to manually running the script from the Apps Script editor. As mentioned in [Google's Quotas docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), *"[...This most commonly occurs for scripts that are triggered, as they have a lower daily limit than scripts executed manually.](https://imgur.com/a/I0zMp3I)"*.

Looking at your script, you are calling Apps Script methods such as `.setValues()` and `getRange()` inside your loop, which is slowing down your script. I would highly recommend considering the use of batch methods for this purpose. [This existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/script-runtime-execution-time-limit/29800759#29800759) in a post will provide you with more insights about it. Hope this helps.