# App Script or Sheets API Copy paste 125k row A:Z data from one google sheet to another. Script Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to copy and paste 125k+ rows of data (columns A:Z) from one google sheet to another. ImportRange will not work due to the data size being too big. Some scripts I have tried have gotten to 30k rows but then it times out. Here is another one i am working with using Sheets API. The error message is "Error
HttpResponseException: Response Code: 413. Message: response too large.
copyDataToTarget    @ copy Data to Target.gs:17"

So it doesn't paste any data.

Here is my Sheets API solution

```
function copyDataToTarget() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = 'Source Sheet ID'; // Source spreadsheet ID
  var sourceRange = 'Sheet1!A2:Z'; // Range in source sheet
  var targetRangeNotation = 'Data!A4:Z'; // Target range notation in target sheet

  // Get the target spreadsheet and sheet
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data');

  // Clear existing data in the target range
  console.log('Clearing existing data in target range');
  targetSheet.getRange(targetRangeNotation).clearContent();

  // Read data from source sheet
  console.log('Reading data from source sheet');
  var sourceData = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sourceSpreadsheetId, sourceRange).values;
  if (!sourceData || sourceData.length === 0) {
    Logger.log('No data found in the source sheet.');
    return;
  }

  // Calculate the number of rows and columns for the target range
  var numRows = sourceData.length;
  var numColumns = sourceData[0].length;
  console.log(numRows,numColumns)
  // Define the target range based on the size of the source data
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(4, 1, numRows, numColumns);

  // Write data to target range
  console.log('Writing data to target sheet');
  targetRange.setValues(sourceData);
  Logger.log('Data copied to target sheet.');
}
```

Resulted in error: Response size too big.

Here is another solution I tried just using App Script:
This one got me to ab 30k rows then it timeout.

```
function batchUploadData() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = 'source ID';
  var targetSheetName = 'Data';
  var startRow = 4; // Start from row 4
  var batchSize = 10000; // Adjust based on performance

  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; // Assuming only one sheet in the source file
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();

  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);

  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i += batchSize) {
    var endRow = Math.min(i + batchSize - 1, lastRow);
    var numRows = endRow - i + 1;
    var data = sourceSheet.getRange(i, 1, numRows, 26).getValues();

    targetSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    startRow += numRows;
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your situation and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

125k+ rows from A to Z amounts to 3.25M+ cells. You might be hitting the practical limits of Google Sheets as a data store (at least I did when I worked with similar volumes). In some cases, I had to migrate to a proper database since Google Sheets could not handle the load.

There are several things you can try (without seeing your data and use case, it is hard to be less generic):

1. Use another type of script, for example, Python, to funnel data between spreadsheets. The timeout limit won't apply there.
2. Switch to Google Workspace paid account: even though the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) still says that their runtime limited to 6 minutes, in practice, I have seen consistent 10+ minute runs on a paid account and no timeouts on my workspace accounts in at least last two years. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14450819/script-runtime-execution-time-limit) claims that it is 30 minutes but I did not find an official proof.
3. Regarding the batched writing approach, if you have a lot of formulas that consume data in the receiving spreadsheet, they will slow down writing each batch. The spreadsheet will need to be finished calculating before you can record the next batch, which can take a long time. You can decouple formulas from the raw data by adding an extra step between where you store the raw data and where these formulas process it. Then, do some pre-processing in-between with Apps Script.
4. Reduce the volume of data transferred as much as possible: both the number of cells and their content. For example, if some cells contain strings with JSON data, you could remove unnecessary fields (if any).
5. Sometimes [advanced IMPORTRANGE techniques](https://dataful.tech/google-sheets/formulas/importrange/result-too-large/) can help (disclosure: this is my website). Although, I wouldn't call them robust or performant.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I thought that [this report (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/cc4380692790150cc090114553e38a0e) might be useful. In this case, I would like to propose a method for splitting the rows as shown in your script.

But, in my proposal, Sheets API is used instead of Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp) for retrieving and putting values for Spreadsheet. By this, the process cost can be reduced and also the batch size can be increased. When your bottom script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function batchUploadData() {
  var sourceSpreadsheetId = 'source ID';
  var targetSheetName = 'Data';
  var startRow = 4; // Start from row 4
  var batchSize = 100000; // Adjust based on performance

  // For source Spreadsheet.
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceSpreadsheetId);
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];
  var sourceSheetName = sourceSheet.getSheetName();
  var lastRow = sourceSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sourceSheet.getLastColumn();

  // For target Spreadsheet.
  var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var targetSpreadsheetId = targetSpreadsheet.getId();
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  var maxRow = targetSheet.getMaxRows();
  var maxCol = targetSheet.getMaxColumns();
  if (maxRow < lastRow) {
    targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(1, lastRow - maxRow);
  }
  if (maxCol < lastCol) {
    targetSheet.insertColumnsAfter(targetSheet.getLastColumn(), lastCol - maxCol);
  }

  // Retrieve values from the source Spreadsheet.
  let start1 = 1;
  const values = [...Array(Math.ceil(lastRow / batchSize))].flatMap((_) => {
    const last = start1 - 1 + batchSize;
    const range = `'${sourceSheetName}'!A${start1}:${last > lastRow ? lastRow : last}`;
    const temp = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(sourceSpreadsheetId, range).values;
    start1 += batchSize;
    return temp;
  });
  console.log(`Data rows: ${values.length}, Data columns: ${values[0].length}`);

  // Put values to target Spreadsheet.
  let start2 = startRow;
  Array.from(Array(Math.ceil(values.length / batchSize))).forEach((_) => {
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: values.splice(0, batchSize) }, targetSpreadsheetId, `'${targetSheetName}'!A${start2}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
    start2 += batchSize;
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- When I tested this script using a sample source Google Spreadsheet with 125,000 rows and 26 columns, the processing time was about 80 seconds.
- In this case, if your target Spreadsheet has several sheets and the total number of cells is over 10,000,000, an error occurs. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [Report: Handling 10,000,000 cells in Google Spreadsheet using Google Apps Script (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/cc4380692790150cc090114553e38a0e)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)